# ISAPI Filter Exception

Tags: iis

I have an exception from IIS
Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll" failed 
I am trying to debug asp.net application and I encountered this problem. Is there any one know how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your ISAPI configuration not correct. For being sure it is correct, you can do this configuration :
Firstly run command prompt and change directory to aspnet_filter.dll location. Secondly run this command :
aspnet_regiis -r or
aspnet_regiis -u + aspnet_regiis -i
This restart your aspnet_regiis. 
Hope this helps